# add permanet PATH in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, path, profile

hi I'm trying to add a permanent path in ubuntu (18.04.5) I have tried with .profile

```
nano ~/.profile 
export PATH="$PATH:~/mytools/my_scripts"
```

then save and source ~/.profile, everything is fine, but if I open a new terminal o restart ubuntu, it is gone, the scripts are not longer available, I have to add a new source, and that is not nice to me.

I have tried with /etc/enviroment as well

```
sudo nano /etc/enviroment

PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:~/mytools/my_scripts"
```

and then

```
source /etc/enviroment
```

an the same problem, each time that open a new terminal the scripts in /mytools/my_scripts is not longer available.

I dont know if I'm using/doing something wrong, how could add all my personal scripts permanently

In Mac it is easy just to add the path to .bash_profile and then source ones and that's all, I don't need source each time that I need my personal scripts/tools.

How can I solve this problem in Ubuntu ????

which file I need to edit just ones ???

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that your changes to `~/.profile` are being erased when you reboot? If so, then the question is what's causing that. Maybe you have something in another startup script that's recreating it. Copy `~/.profile` to another file, then reboot, then compare it to the copy. Check the timestamps (`ls -l`).

If you're using bash (you probably are if you haven't changed it), then updating `.bash_profile` as you do on Mac should work the same way on Ubuntu.

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't make account-specific changes to a system-wide file like `/etc/environment` (whose name you misspelled in your question, BTW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Solution:**

Try replacing `~/mytools/my_scripts` with `/home/your_username/mytools/my_scripts` in your `.profile` OR use `$HOME` variable instead like this.

```
PATH="$HOME/mytools/my_scripts:$PATH"
```

**Second Solution**

Copy all of your scripts to `/usr/bin`

```
cp ~/mytools/my_scripts/* /usr/bin/
```

Comment: I wouldn't copy account-specific scripts to a system-wide directory like `/usr/bin`. If you want personal binaries, put them in a directory under your home directory.

Comment: @KeithThompson Would it be acceptable if the scripts names are unique? Otherwise, why would it be discouraged?

Comment: thanks so much it works with PATH="$HOME/mytools/my_scripts:$PATH", but I don't know why with /etc/environment recognize the script.py but at the time to execute, it don't work, it say "command not found", but with .prifile it works fine.... Thanks

Comment: `$HOME` variable contains the home path of the current user. Like @KeithThompson said, `/etc/environment` is a system-wide configuration file, and shouldn't be user-specific, so `$HOME` probably got interpreted it as `root` user home path.

Comment: @Samy I don't know how `$HOME` would be interpreted in `/etc/environment`. It *might* expand to the home directory of the current user.

Comment: Unix is designed as a multi-user system, even if a lot of installations are for one person's use. I find it useful to keep a clear distinction between system-wide information and user-specific information. If you want your own `~/my_scripts` to be in your `$PATH`, you don't need to do that in `/etc/environment`. (If the system really is multi-user, `~/my_scripts` likely won't exist for another user account -- or, it might exist but not be something the user wants in `$PATH`.